# How to add an md5 checksum for my Android requests to PHP

Tags: php, android

So, I have an Android app and I need to verify all of the requests made to my server. Can someone explain or show me how to make and send the checksum of the request in Android and verifying in PHP?

Comment: serialize your request to a string, and generate it's hash. On the PHP side do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can encrypt your request to md5 with following code in android side

```
public static final String md5(final String s) {
final String MD5 = "MD5";
try {
    // Create MD5 Hash
    MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest
            .getInstance(MD5);
    digest.update(s.getBytes());
    byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

    // Create Hex String
    StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte aMessageDigest : messageDigest) {
        String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & aMessageDigest);
        while (h.length() < 2)
            h = "0" + h;
        hexString.append(h);
    }
    return hexString.toString();

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return "";
}
```

same in php side you have to decrypt the same request with md5 for use